# How to produce a graph which shows percentage instead of number of occurrences using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn, percentage

I have 1000 customers with varying tenures and contract statuses(1 means that they're in contract whereas 0 mean they're out of contract) as shown by the dataframe below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['customer','tenure','contract_status'])
df['customer'] = np.arange(1001)
df['tenure'] = np.random.randint(1,200, df.shape[0]) 
df['contract_status'][:200] = 0
df['contract_status'][200:] = 1
```

I have a created a histogram to illustrate the distribution of customers in and out of contract using the code below:

```py
sns.set_context('talk')
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,8)
plt.hist(df[df['contract_status'] == 1]['tenure'], bins = 50,alpha=0.5, label='Contract')
plt.hist(df[df['contract_status'] ==0]['tenure'], bins = 50, alpha=0.5, label='Non - contract')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('tenure')
plt.title('Distribution of customers')
plt.show()
```

Below is a sample of what I have tried and the expected solution:

```
> exp = df[(df['tenure']>0) & (df['tenure']<10)]

>  exp_plot = exp.groupby(['contract_status',
> 'tenure']).size().reset_index().pivot(columns='contract_status', index
> ='tenure', values=0)
>     exp_plot['In contract'] = ((exp_plot[1]/(exp_plot[0] + exp_plot[1])) * 100).round(2)
>     exp_plot['Out of contract'] = ((exp_plot[0]/(exp_plot[0] + exp_plot[1])) * 100).round(2)
>     exp_plot.drop([0,1],axis=1,inplace=True)

>     fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,8))
>     exp_plot.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,ax =ax)
>     ax.set(xlabel = 'tenure',ylabel='Percentage of customers',title= 'tenure' + 
>     by percentage',ylim=(0,100))
>     ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
>     
>     for p in ax.patches:
>         width, height = p.get_width(), p.get_height()
>         x, y = p.get_xy() 
>         ax.text(x+width/2,  y+height/2, '{:.1f}%'.format(height), 
>          horizontalalignment='center', 
>         verticalalignment='center',size=14,color='white')
```

This solution only works for a few data points - as shown above I only used this example for tenures which fall between 0 and 10. When I try to apply it to the whole dataframe it doesn't turn out right.

I would like to create a graph- something similar to a stacked bar chart -to show the distribution in terms of percentage instead of number of occurrences whereby each bar would go up to 1 and the colour shaded in would represent the number of customers either in or out of contract for each tenure instance.

Comment: I would suggest to write up a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and detail a bit better what you get right now and what you would like to get instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`np.histogram()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) has a `density` keyword, and if that is set to `True` it would produce a normalized histogram. I would have been surprised if [`plt.hist()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) would not have supported the very same feature.

It should be enough to modify, e.g. this:

```
plt.hist(df[df['contract_status'] == 1]['tenure'], bins = 50,alpha=0.5, label='Contract')
```

into this:

```
plt.hist(df[df['contract_status'] == 1]['tenure'], bins = 50, density=True, alpha=0.5, label='Contract')
```

(also, perhaps you should consider `df.plot()` as well, if it is just quick & dirty plotting).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but I want something similar to a stacked bar chart whereby each tenure would show what percentage of customers are in and out contract.